# Cordova: LocalFileSystem is not defined

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, html5-filesystem, ionic-framework

I am not able to get the cordova file system to work. I have a project with the following dependencies:

```
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.3 "Keyboard"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.12 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.13 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.8 "File Transfer"
```

In `app.js` I define a dependency on a controller module:

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'controllers']);
```

The controller code is basically this:

```js
angular.module('controllers', [])
  .controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope) {
    function success() {...}
    function error() {...}
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
  }
}
```

What I then get is:

```js
LocalFileSystem is not defined
```

Also, `requestFileSystem` is undefined. What could be the reason for this behavior?

I am using cordova 4.1.2 and ionic 1.3.1.

**EDIT:** This is the according html markup:

```xml
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="GalleryCtrl">
<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-slide-box id="slideBox">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="..."> <!-- details omitted -->
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply aren't waiting for *deviceReady* event to be fired and thus the File plugin isn't loaded yet. Change

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { 
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
}, false);
```

The *LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT* might be undefined even after that (has been for me while emulating etc.) but it can be replaced with *1* as it is just a constant.

Comment: I should add that apparently the file-transfer plugin prevented the `deviceready` event from being triggered. After removing this plugin and registering above event listener every worked fine.

Comment: Note that because of the title of this question people like me may come here that they simply didn't add cordova file plugin, the solution: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons for the requestFileSystem not being available is because the device is not ready.

Try running the code once the window is ready:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(event, data) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
});
```

I get the LocalFileSystem is not defined in my editor because its a plugin (from my understanding) but once the window is loaded I can use the requestFileSystem and LocalFileSystem works as expected.

Comment: While your approach suppresses the error messages it does so by just not firing the `$ionicView.enter` event. Hence, `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);` is never executed. Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score -1):

For ionic inject `$ionicPlatform` and then use :

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {       
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
}, false);
```