# Uncaught Reference Error: LocalFileSystem not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3, cordova-plugins

This question has been asked before on this forum but I could not find a satisfactory solution to the problem. Hence the question again. 
I am trying to download and store a file from the internet into the local file system on my phone. I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined`

The code I have so far is:

```
function storeFile(bucketName, csvfile){
   var region;
   s3Client.getBucketLocation(params = {Bucket: bucketName},function(err,data){
       if(err) console.log("Error :: Cannot retrieve bucket location", err);
       else {
          console.log(data);
          region = data;
       }
    });

   var url = "http://s3-"+region+".amazonaws.com/"+bucketName+"/"+csvfile;
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,
     function(fs){
       filePath = fs.root.fullPath + "/" + csvfile;
       fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
       fileTransfer.download(url, filePath, 
        function (entry) {
          console.log(entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
        }, 
        function (error) {
           console.log("Some error");
        });
    }, function(err){
       console.log("Request File System failure");
   });
}
```

Do I need to add any plugins into my app? I already have the File and FileTransfer plugins added. By the way this function is called after onDeviceReady is fired.

**EDITED:**
I am not working with AngularJs. My code is on NodeJs. Secondly, I have no dependencies like the ionic framework etc. which could possibly present a problem. This same code has been tested on other data which have been successfully downloaded and stored. The problem has occurred after I changed the code to download from a specific location on the amazon server. If someone could address this problem for me, it would be great. I am able to access the bucket and the region through code. The only problem is the LocalFileSystem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova: LocalFileSystem is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985512/cordova-localfilesystem-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve the problem. Just removed and re-added the file and file-transfer plugins.

`cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file` and `cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file-transfer` to remove.

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file` and `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer` to add.

It may tell you that these plugins are soon to be deprecated or something like that. You also have the option of using the later versions. To add you can use

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer`. Just check if they are available under the respective builds in the platforms folder.